# Show/Hide & Mouseover Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover, show-hide

I been researching on Show/Hide javascript and pushed it further with a mouseover effect to achieve what I want. I've set up a Fiddle for better accessibility. However, I now want to push it by having up to 4 different text areas ("Click here for more information"), and each text area would have more hover text as I tried to show in the HTML code itself. The javascript that I used and edited now has "ID"s corresponding to "0" and "1" which wouldnt work for my current HTML code as it has funky names like "uu3308-10" (made with Adobe Muse). **Now, I'm wonder what variables would I have to change within the Javascript to make it function properly** and is there a way to compile this code so it works with at least 11 other "Click here for more information" points?

Note: The current javascript makes showMoreText2 appear under both showMoreText areas (would like to make only one hover text appear at a time).

**CLICK HERE FOR THE FIDDLE -- >** http://jsfiddle.net/TPLOR/vy6nS/

Thanks, I hope this was helpful enough. =)

Comment: Can you clarify the result you are trying to achieve? Fiddles are fine, but it's helpful to see code / desired output in the question itself, to maximise the chances of people helping.

Comment: 1) You click on "Click here for more information" and then "Here, you will find some more information" pops up, and when you hover over "Here, you will find some more information", you get more a div with more information. So its a show/hide effect, with a mouseover added for more information - basically 3 different levels of information presented. The 2nd level has 4 different text areas too.

Comment: Be careful of how your mouseover ideas will translate for mobile users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kinda hackish: (see http://jsfiddle.net/vy6nS/30/ )

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName("expander");
    for (i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++) {
        elems2 = elems1[i].childNodes;
        for (x = 0; x < elems2.length; x++) {
            if (elems2[x].className == "toggle") elems2[x].onclick = function() {
                showMore(0, this);
            };
            else if (elems2[x].className == "showMoreText") {
                elems2[x].onmouseover = function() {
                    showChilds("block", this);
                };
                elems2[x].onmouseout = function() {
                    showChilds("none", this);
                };
            }
        }
    }
};

function get_nextsibling(n) {
    x = n.nextSibling;
    while (x.nodeType != 1) {
        x = x.nextSibling;
    }
    return x;
}

function showChilds(disp, elem) {
    get_nextsibling(elem).style.display = disp;
}

function showMore(disp, elem) {
    var children = elem.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (disp == 0 && children[i].className == "showMoreText") {
            children[i].style.display = children[i].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
        }
    }

}​
```

Comment: Thanks mightyuhu, what variables would I add so I can have two more points such as "3 Here, you will find some more information" and "4 Here, you will find some more information" with their own respective mouseover text?